# Installing Conda using a non bash shell

Tags: python, bash, shell, anaconda

My work defaults to tcsh for all linux and mac machines for unknown 'historical' reasons. We are trying to get a bunch of our code out to the public using Conda. But Conda appears to be bash only implementation which for the rest of the world is not a problem. I was not able to get it to install in a tcsh shell and I found some references to zsh in the Conda [troubleshooting guide](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/troubleshooting.html) but I can't tell if Conda is a bash only implementation or if it will actually work in other shells. While I can easily start bash from a tcsh terminal window, it is a minor annoyance.

So what I want to know is: does Conda work in other shell types, if not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with using `conda` outside of bash or zsh is that it requires the `activate` and `deactivate` scripts to modify the local environment, meaning that they must be sourced rather than executed in a subshell. The second statement in `activate` checks that you are running from one of the supported shells:

```
# Determine the directory containing this script
if [[ -n $BASH_VERSION ]]; then
    _SCRIPT_LOCATION=${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
elif [[ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]]; then
    _SCRIPT_LOCATION=${funcstack[1]}
else
    echo "Only bash and zsh are supported"
    return 1
fi
```

There is nothing much you can do about that. However, I have had luck using an existing conda environment when I manually set the `PATH` variable in `tcsh`: if you prefix the `bin` folder of your root or custom environment to `PATH`, you should be able to get things going.

I am not sure if you can (never tried to) install conda or modify environments outside of `bash` though.

Comment: So Conda is effectively written around bash and zsh shells. I don't think I'll chance it trying to use another shell.

Comment: @veda905. That's about the size of it. They were targeting the majority of users, which means mostly bash and more of zsh in coming years. While this is unfortunate in the immediate sense, it may propmt your company to use a more feature-rich shell than tcsh.

Answer (score 5):

This is a really late add-on to the whole discussion. But it might help other people running into the same problems. Unfortunately, I have only tried this in a tcsh shell.

As stated in the [conda installation guidelines](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html), it is not much of an issue anymore to run conda in other shells than bash (i.e. using bash installer.sh). As of conda 4.4. there seems to be now a `conda activate myenv` function. 
And with conda 4.6. there is a `conda init` script, which should add all the necessary things to use `conda activate myenv` (rather than source activate myenv) in the necessary profile files (~/.bashrc, ~/.tcshrc, etc.). So that it can be run with multiple shells.

However, this still doesn't seem to work flawlessly with Miniconda3 and conda 4.6 (conda init tcsh, throwing an error, there is an issue open on github). 
But I found a possible solution on [github](https://github.com/ESMValGroup/ESMValTool/issues/301). By adding `source <prefix>/minicondaX/etc/profile.d/conda.csh` to your ~/.tcshrc file you should be able to use `conda activate myenv` in tcsh.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Anaconda supports several non bash kernels with native support for TCSH included. Simply run the following:

```
<path to minicondaORanaconda>/bin/conda init tcsh
```

and restart your terminal. Done !!

This command would create a `.tcshrc` file with following entry

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
if ( -f "/local/mnt/workspace/mohit/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh" ) then
    source "/local/mnt/workspace/mohit/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh"
else
    setenv PATH "/local/mnt/workspace/mohit/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
endif
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

where `/local/mnt/workspace/mohit/` is location of my miniconda directory.